# The following assertion was thrown during runApp: Zone mismatch. FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart

The Flutter bindings were initialized in a different zone than is now being used. This will likely
cause confusion and bugs as any zone-specific configuration will inconsistently use the
configuration of the original binding initialization zone or this zone based on hard-to-predict
factors such as which zone was active when a particular callback was set.
It is important to use the same zone when calling `ensureInitialized` on the binding as when calling
`runApp` later.

To make this warning fatal, set BindingBase.debugZoneErrorsAreFatal to true before the bindings are
initialized (i.e. as the first statement in `void main() { }`).